# Trying to Display color name at every click check my code

Tags: java, android, android-activity, colors

I have this segment in my game where the circle draws different colors, i want the players to be able to see the color names at every click displayed on `Toast` How can i achieve that? my code is below. Any help will be appreciated? I want to display them in String Form Eg. if the RGB is red it displays Red inform of string.

```
static int x,y,r=255,g=255,b=255;
    final static int radius=180;
    Paint paint;

    public Circle(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);


        setFocusable(true);


        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);


        canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,paint);

    }
```

Comment: When you say get color, do you mean the name in String form or just the RGB values? Example: Red vs. R:255, B:0, G:0

Comment: any help ? how can i achieve that?

Comment: Yup! one sec, i'll answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to strictly match color names to RGB values, you are going to need to match the randomized RGB to known colors of your choosing. For example you could do something like this with a ColorUtils class:

```
class ColorUtils{

public static final Map<String, int[]> COLOR_MAP;

static{
    COLOR_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    COLOR_MAP.put("red",  new int[]{255,0,0});
    COLOR_MAP.put("blue", new int[]{0, 0, 255});
    COLOR_MAP.put("green", new int[]{0, 255,0});
    ...
    ...   //add more colors here
}

public static double findDist(int[] rgb, int[] color){
    int deltaR = color[0] - rgb[0];
    int deltaG = color[1] - rgb[1];
    int deltaB = color[2] - rgb[2];
    return (Math.pow(deltaR, 2) + Math.pow(deltaG, 2) + Math.pow(deltaB, 2));
}

public static String findClosestColor(int[] rgb, Map<String, int[]> colorMap){
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String color = null;
    double dist;
    for(Entry<String, int[]> entry : colorMap.entrySet()){
        dist = findDist(rgb, entry.getValue());
        if(dist < min){
            dist = min;
            color = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return color;
}
}
```

Test like so:

```
int[] teal =  {2, 132, 130};
System.out.print(findClosestColor(teal, colorMap));
```

For you to test in Android:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event){
    x=(int)event.getX()-(radius/2);
    y=(int)event.getY()-(radius/2);
    randColor();
    invalidate();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), 
        ColorUtils.findClosestColor(new int[]{r, g, b}, ColorUtils.COLOR_MAP), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

For your sake, add those two methods to a utilities class, and also statically create the color map, where you will populate it with colors you wish to express to the user. There is no known library (TO MY KNOWLEDGE!) that has the ability to map RGB to colors that is easily accessible in Java. I could be wrong, but I also think this is your best way.

Note: It would also be better to store the Toast.makeText() call as another method in a separate utils class (I do this if I use Toasts) so it cleans the code up a bit

```
class AndroidUtils{

    public static void createToast(Context context, String str){
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Then just call this instead for above's toast:

```
AndroidUtils.createToast(getContext(), ColorUtils.findClosestColor(new int[]{r, g, b}, ColorUtils.COLOR_MAP));
```

Comment: This makes sense but i dont understand the last (Test like so) is that the toast?

Comment: Sorry, this is indeed for Android so maybe I should have given you a better example to test on.. one sec. (I wrote this in native java just because it is easier)

Comment: right, it is editted. You should have access to getContext() since I'm assuming Circle is of type View